# Android O build system, did not sync linkfile in manifest.xml

Tags: android-8.0-oreo

When I reso sync with `repo init -u git://codeaurora.org/platform/manifest.git -b release -m LA.UM.6.6.r1-04000-89xx.0.xml --repo-url=git://codeaurora.org/tools/repo.git`

In manifest.xml, All file in linkfile section did not sync.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `--repo-branch=aosp-new/stable` at the end of your repo init line.

The repo tool fetched from codeaurora when no branch is specified is too old (version v1.7.5).

In aosp-new/stable branch, the repo version used is v1.12.37 and fix this bug.